# Analytical continuation by contour rotation

Tags: complex-analysis

reading a paper by Langer (Theory of the Condensation Point, Annals of Physics 41, 108-157, 1967), I came across an analytical continuation technique which I do not understand (would like to upload the paper PDF but I am not so sure this is allowed). Essentially, he deals with the integral $$ \int_{0} ^{\infty} \mathrm{d} t \quad t^2 e^ {-\frac{A}{H}(t^3+t^2)} $$, $A$ being a constant.
 His aim is to analytically continue this function for negative $H$, over the singularity at $0$. He starts by considering the real part of $t ^2 +t ^3$ , showing two saddle point at $0$ and $ -2/3$. Then he says, let us start with positive, real only H and move it around the origin in the complex plan, anticlockwise (the same will be repeated clockwise). The "array of three valleys and mountains, given by $ \frac{-t^3}{H^2}$ for large $ t$, also moves anticlockwise. And as they say, so far, so good, but now the bit that puzzles me. "The analytical continuation of $ f(H)$ is obtained, according to a standard and rigorous construction, by rotating the contour $ C_1$, going from $0 $ to infinity on the real axis, so that it always remains at the bottom of its original valley, and a picture shows the countour $ C_2 $ going from $ 0$ to $-2/3$ along the negative real axis, and then up tp the top left along one of the "valleys". Once, he adds, $ H$ is moved to $  H_2 = e^{i \pi} $, the integrand has returned to its original form, but $f(H_2)$ is obtained integrating along the rotated countour $C_2$. I understand that the integrand will return to its original form, but why rotating the contour? If anybody had a hint, that would be so appreciated, thanks. I appreciate the question might sound obstruse, really it would make better sense with the related paper, I just hoping the above sounds obvious to somebody, thanks again.